# Refresh page title every 10 seconds - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to refresh my page title every 10 seconds to ensure that the song info changes here:

[image]

But after the song changes, I am left with the same page title:

[image]

My JavaScript setInterval function isn't working correctly.

Here's my code (what should have worked):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function songToTitle() {
    document.title = "BDR | <?php echo $radio_info['now_playing']; ?>";
}
songToTitle();
setInterval(songToTitle, 10000);
</script>
<title>BDR | Loading Song Title...</title>
```

I don't really know what's up here.

It imports the song name correctly, but does not refresh.

Can anyone help me with this?

**EDIT:**

I tried using this too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function songTitle(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.title.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.x86cam.com/wp-content/plugins/songTitle.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
songTitle();
setInterval(songTitle, 5000);
</script>
```

It won't even load the title.

Comment: One does not simply mix JS and PHP like that. The Code will only execute _ONCE_, and that is when the site is loaded.

Comment: hahahaha thank you for posting that

Comment: need to tie into API of media player....how are songs managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I figured it out.
I put this in my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function songTitle(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.title=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","songTitle.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
songTitle();
setInterval(songTitle, 5000);
</script>
```

In my `songTitle.php`, it requests the song name from the Icecast server and displays only that.

Whenever the song changes now, it also changes the title.

I just had to integrate an XMLHTTPRequest like I did with how I displayed the song info on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use that php code in there, it's not going to execute when the function runs because PHP ran at the server, the code is now running in your browser, so once the song changes, that string is still going to be the exact same string it was when the browser asked your server for that .html file

You'll have to ask your server what the current title is using an xhr call ever X seconds and then refresh the title based on that.

Comment: @charlietfl NOT ENOUGH JQUERY.

Comment: @charlietfl good point, I didn't realise it was in DOM1. As far as "more jquery" goes, SO users love jQuery more than they should, so JS answers that combine a plain JS and jQuery answer tend to be more useful to visitors. Even if you irrationally hate it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You are refreshing a static piece of information.  To get new information you must use AJAX.

PHP is loaded before your browser opens it.

In other words...

```
<?php echo $radio_info['now_playing']; ?>
```

turns into

```
'Song Name'
```

so when Javascript looks at it, it only sees `Song Name` and is none the wiser.

**[AJAX Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)** - complete API reference with examples down the page for you to fork off of.  Your responding page also needs to be programmed to respond correctly.  Usually I suggest JSON but this you can probably just use a text transfer since it's so little data.

You can send the data using `POST` and the PHP file can have something like this at the top:

```
<?php if ($_POST['songcheck'] === true) { echo $songName; return; }; ?>
```

**PS - refreshing every 10 seconds isn't very efficient.  When the song is loaded, use the song length +2 or +3 seconds for the timer instead.  Much better :)**

Comment: Edited question, can you tell me what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do an ajax call or listen to a some event to retrieve updated song title. The `document.title = "BDR | <?php echo $radio_info['now_playing']; ?>";` string is generated on initial page load.